# Insert 1 bit in number c#

Tags: c#, insert, numbers, bit

I have problem with inserting a bit in number. I have a position where to insert this 1 bit. For example if i have a number 186 (represent in bits: 1011 1010) and I have a position 4. It will looks 1 011**1** 1010. And my second problem is almost the same as first but the operation is remove 1 bit in given position. If i have position 5, the number in bits will look 101 1010. Thank you

Keep calm and learn how to

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Sorry I didn't write the programming language.. I am using C#

Comment: Tags should not be included in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.Collections.BitArray` for this task, it allows you to convert a number to a bit array, then manipulate individual bits of this number, then convert it back. Here's how you could insert a `bit` into a `number` at a certain `position`:

```
    public static byte insertIntoPosition(byte number, int position, bool bit)
    {
        // converting the number to BitArray
        BitArray a = new BitArray (new byte[]{number});

        // shifting the bits to the left of the position
        for (int j = a.Count - 1; j > position; j--) {
            a.Set (j, a.Get (j - 1));
        }

        // setting the position bit
        a.Set (position, bit);

        // converting BitArray to byte again
        byte[] array = new byte[1];
        a.CopyTo(array, 0);
        return array[0];
    }
```

Removing a bit from a certain position is also easily done this way.

Comment: Downvoted, because this is inefficient. You should use a for loop for simple bit-twiddling.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do exactly the same for my [Z80.NET project](https://bitbucket.org/konamiman/z80dotnet) and that's how I solved it:

```
public static class NumberUtils
{
    public static byte WithBit(this byte number, int bitPosition, bool value)
    {
        if(bitPosition < 0 || bitPosition > 7)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("bit position must be between 0 and 7");

        if(value) 
            return (byte)(number | (1 << bitPosition));
        else 
            return (byte)(number & ~(1 << bitPosition));
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
[Test]
public void SetBit_works_for_middle_bit()
{
    byte bit4reset = 0xFF;
    Assert.AreEqual(0xEF, bit4reset.WithBit(4, false));

    byte bit4set = 0x00;
    Assert.AreEqual(0x10, bit4set.WithBit(4, true));
}
```

Comment: Your code simply sets or resets the bit at the specified position. OP wanted to insert or delete the bit, shifting leftmost bits to the left or to the right correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will insert a single bit without the inefficiency of converting to a bit array with a for loop (turning a O(1) operation into a O(N) one).

```
public static int InsertBit(int input, int pos, bool state) {
  //Split the input into two parts, one shifted and one not
  int bottom = input;
  int top = (input << 1);
  //insert a '0' or '1' before the shifted part
  if (state) top |= (1 << pos);
  else       top &= (~(1 << pos));
  //keep the top bits of top
  top &= (-1 << pos);
  //keep the bottom bits of bottom
  bottom &= ~(-1 << pos);
  //combine the two parts.
  return (bottom | top);
end;
```

Note that is is a translation of https://www.topbug.net/blog/2014/11/16/how-to-insert-1-bit-into-an-integer/
So not my own code.

Removing a bit is even easier:

```
public static int RemoveBit(int input, int pos) {
  //Split the input into two parts, one shifted and one not
  int bottom = input;
  int top = (input >> 1);
  //keep the top bits of x
  top &= (-1 << pos);
  //keep the bottom bits of y
  bottom &= ~(-1 << pos);
  //combine the two parts.
  return (bottom | top);
end;
```

Note that remove bit will preserve the sign of `input`. If `input` is negative then it will insert `1`'s into the most significant bit. If you don't want that you'll have to make input an `unsigned int`.